# MySQL with JOIN-Query

Tags: mysql

I want to connect differend Queries with each other, but I can't figure out a way how...

---

Table *mcr_versions* contains a list of plugin versions, I want to get the **plugin_id** of the last 10 updates:

```
SELECT plugin_id FROM mcr_versions ORDER BY time DESC LIMIT 10
```

At the next step I need to get the plugin from another table:

```
SELECT id, name, logo, rating FROM mcr_plugins WHERE id = plugin_id
```

---

Now I have a table containing plugin-category-relationships, only with **plugin_id** and **cat_id**, I want to get one **cat_id** for each plugin:

```
SELECT cat_id FROM mcr_plugin_cat WHERE plugin_id = id
```

The last table contains the name of the category:

```
SELECT name FROM mcr_categories WHERE id = cat_id
```

---

How can I connect these queries to one query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select mcr_categories.name from mcr_versions
left join mcr_plugins on mcr_plugins.id = mcr_versions.plugin_id
left join plugin-category-relationships on plugin-category-relationships.plugin_id = mcr_versions.plugin_id
left join mcr_categories on mcr_categories.cat_id =  plugin-category-relationships.cat_id
order by mcr_versions.time desc limit 10;
```

i may be wrong at some of the tables , but i beleive u got my point

Comment: Thank you very much! I only added the other columns (mcr_plugin.name etc) and now it works well.